# Navigation Drawer with collapsable navigation items

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I would like to move from a standard NavigationDrawer which uses the ActionBar and Fragments and implement Collapsible navigation items as detailed in these pictures: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lF0cc.jpg) (Something like Item 4).

I understand I have to use an ExpandableListView, but am not sure how to implement that into my current setup.

`MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks, atcCTIFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, atcSectionWebFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

//Variables for the download portion
public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

    Fragment fragment = new atcSectionWebFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new atcSectionWebFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new atcCTIFragment();
            break;
    }

    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();


    switch (position) {
        case 1:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, atcDictionary.class);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
}


public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
        case 4:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section4);
            break;
        case 5:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section5);
    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
<!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. -->
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.fascination.atcassistantlitev2.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

If anyone knows of a tutorial showing this that I could follow so I could learn how to implement this that would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the `ListView` in the `NavigationDrawerFragment` to `ExpandableListView` and add logic to show the options when the user clicks on list item. You'll also have to move the logic to update the UI on the right side on `onClick` method of the expanded item.